# How to find which client is being used by a validator?

Tags: clients, validators

I would like to find out which **client** is being used by a given validator.

For example; [this](https://beaconcha.in/validator/8e323fd501233cd4d1b9d63d74076a38de50f2f584b001a5ac2412e4e46adb26d2fb2a6041e7e8c57cd4df0916729219) is an active Ethereum validator. Where can i find which client this validator is using? Is it a public info? I searched it on beaconcha.in but couldn't find any client info.

Comment: Ok, i got something but still not what i am looking for.. I found this api gives number of clients in a given epoch but no details which one belong to whom.. https://api.blockprint.sigp.io/blocks_per_client/144734

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to find out which validator is running which client.

Some validators will use the default graffiti from their client and that graffiti will include the name of the client. You can tell by looking at some of [the recent blocks](https://beaconcha.in/blocks). Check out in the graffiti column. That's probably one of the best way to figure it out. A graffiti can be anything and someone can choose any graffiti so it's not fool proof.

The second best way to figure out which client is used by a validator is with [Michael Sproul blockprint project](https://github.com/sigp/blockprint). It is not foolproof and it comes with some uncertainty but it will analyse how the blocks were constructed and come up with the best guest on which client did that block construction.

A good chart and resources on client diversity can be found on https://clientdiversity.org/. That website uses the blockprint project as one of its sources.